# How do I loop through a sparse matrix to build target variable for specific columns in a loop and using the rest of the matrix as features

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix stored as np z-compressed file. Below is how the loaded data looks like from the file. I have a list of target variables, for which I want to split the matrix into target and feature variables in a loop.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
i = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2])
j = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,0,5,6,3,7,0,5,8,2,9,7])
data = np.array([10,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,1])
visits = np.array(['vis_num_1','vis_num_2','vis_num_3'])
features = np.array(['feature_1','feature_4','codes_a','codes_b','codes_c','feature_6','codes_d','codes_e','feature_2','codes_g'])
sp_mat = sp.coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), shape=(len(visits), len(features)))
sp_mat = sp_mat.tocsr()
target_list = ['feature_1','feature_4']

#TODO - loop through target_list to create target variable array and feature variable arrays

print(sp_mat.toarray())

Out:
array([[10,  2,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  2,  1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  3,  1]], dtype=int32)

target_arr, feature_arr = sp_mat[:, :1].toarray(), sp_mat[:, 1:].toarray()
print(target_arr)
Out: 
array([[10],
       [ 1],
       [ 2]], dtype=int32)
print(feature_arr)
Out: 
array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Your code is not valid python. Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: made the corrections

Comment: Thanks. You shouldn't need to loop (do you need to?). I think that `target_arr, feature_arr = sp_mat[:, :2], sp_mat[:, 2:]` might do what you want?

Comment: further edited the question to include example. I want to loop through the target and feature array from the list, so one row becomes the target and the other rows become features - for each feature.